# NiFi using Clickhouse Driver NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: apache-nifi, clickhouse

In NiFi i use Clickhouse Driver. When i "enable" DBCPConnectionPool with driver, i get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.

[screen of settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiGCV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Clickhouse Driver is not a standalone JAR, it [has dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ru.yandex.clickhouse/clickhouse-jdbc/0.1.1) such as Guava. You'd have to download all the dependencies along with the driver JAR, put them all in a folder, and point to the folder in the Database Driver Location(s) property.

Comment: Thanks. I add Guava in lib folder, reload nifi and Configuration started without problem.
But Processor, that use ConnectionPool show error: Failed while executing one of the processors OnSheduled task. I open logs/nifi-app.log and saw here 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 ... 34 common frames omitted

Comment: Guava isn't the only dependency. Check the list in the link I sent, you'll need all the compile dependencies and any transitive dependencies as well.

Comment: Thanks. I download Clickhouse Driver from git and package it with dependencies. It working!