# can't connect to Clickhouse database using apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, clickhouse

I am trying to connect to the Clickhouse database Using Apache Nifi. I can't fix this error.

NIFI 1.12.1

```sh
StandardControllerServiceNode[service=DBCPConnectionPool[id=f73ad0c3-0176-1000-0546-94e4c6c6fe9b],
     versionedComponentId=null,
     processGroup=StandardProcessGroup[identifier=f73973ae-0176-1000-a421-ff32b5b5cb70,name=NiFi Flow], active=true] 
Failed to invoke @OnEnabled method due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
Could not initialize class ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseDriver: 
Could not initialize class ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseDriver
```

**Please check images**

[image: Image -1]

[image: Image -2]

Comment: the error message indicates there is no class defined, have you added it in your class path ?

Comment: Where did you get that .jar ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45591760/12169451 @DennyCrane

Comment: @alisalem download https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc/releases/tag/release_0.2.4 clickhouse-jdbc-0.2.4-shaded.jar
5.41 MB

Comment: Thanks @DennyCrane

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that the class `ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseDriver` can't be found.

Ensure that you:

1. Have the right jar
2. The jar exists in the right path
3. The user running NiFi has permissions on the jar
4. You are using the correct Class name for the Driver in the jar